# Displaying a new image instead of another image button in a UITableView infront of every cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I want to add an image on top of another image button in a table view controller as soon as that button gets clicked. I have UIButton *button in .h file.

```
    CellForRow:{
    button=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230,0,40,40); 
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:withEvent:)                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"a"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell addSuBView:button];
[cell setIndentationWidth:1];
[cell setIndendationLevel:1];
}
-(void)buttonPressed:(id) sender withEvent: (UIEvent *) event{
UIButton *mybtn=(UIButton*) sender;
[mybtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"b"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

What this does is displays the second image on top of the first. But what I want is to get the new image in place of the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
button.selected = ! button.selected;

                if (button.selected) {
                    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
                else{
                    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                }

}
```

Comment: its working...but requires a double click to get the image changed.

Comment: and again changes to the previous image on subsequent clicks